# AWS Custom Metrics and Metrics Insights - best practice

Tags: monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, application-insights

I have a reasonably large app running in AWS and using DynamoDB. I would like to have detailed information about which parts of my app and which users are consuming read/write units in DynamoDB. Each lamdba invoke can use multiple put/get/query commands.

I have added code to capture the total RCU and WCU for each lambda invoke, and want to send these as custom metrics to CloudWatch.

There are three main dimensions I'm interested in: "UserId", application "Command" (endpoint) and "Item". I experimented with sending the following:

```
[
  {
    MetricName: "RCU",
    Value: 42,
    Dimensions: [
      { Name: "UserId", Value: "foo" }, 
      { Name: "Command", Value: "bar" },
      { Name: "Item", Value: "a" }
    ]
  },
  {
    MetricName: "RCU",
    Value: 42,
    Dimensions: [
      { Name: "UserId", Value: "foo" }, 
      { Name: "Command", Value: "bar" },
      { Name: "Item", Value: "a" }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the CloudWatch "Multi source query" tab I can then query, sort descending and cut to view the top consumers along the different dimensions, but only for the last 3 hours.

In the "Browse" tab, this approach doesn't work at all, because the implicit schema "UserId, Command, Item" shows the cross product of all users, commands and items, and I have a lot of users and items.

I can push individual metrics with single dimensions, but I cannot see how this would enable me to sort and cut data over more than three hours, to find the highest consuming users/commands/items.

Any advice appreciated.